# Who can show me the details of this solved problem concerning the deflation rate of a "soft" tank?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Thanks to @stochastic the [solution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405085/how-can-i-find-the-deflation-rate-of-a-balloon) is given for this problem. However, I'm rather novice and need some intermediate steps to understand fully the development.

**1)** I don't get this type of writing for the differential equation? (Sorry, for this basic question!) $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dn} g(P-P_{out}) \Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt} = \left.\frac{dh}{dn}\right|_{h^{-1}(V)} g(f(V)-P_{out})$$
the $ \boxed{\left.\frac{dh}{dn}\right|_{h^{-1}(V)}} $
Could someone show me express it in another way?

And then if you have the kindness to give me some hints for the next stages of the math resolution, I would be grateful.

$V = h(n) = \frac{-P_{out}+\sqrt{P_{out}^2+4k n R T}}{2k}$ ...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As per the solution you sent, $\left.\frac{dh}{dn}\right|_{h^{-1}(V)}$ is just reaffirming that $V=h(n)$ and so if $P=f(V)$ on the right side, it only makes sense to put in $n$ on the derivative if $h(n)=V$, I guess you could rewrite it as:
$\left. \frac{dh}{dn}\right|_{h(n)=V}$

Comment: Thank you @DavidMelo. Then would you have the plunk to show me how to solve this  differential equation ?